# How to retrieve all contact from selected gmail account in android

Tags: android, contacts, account

I want to fetch contact of user but only of selected account,user may have more than one account in android then how to fetch contact of particular account..i know how to fetch all account.

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer just need to add  ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME in projection of query and then sort your data according to account name.